# Issue with useState() being asynchronous

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a state object:

```
const [offersList, setOffersList] = useState(currentOffers)
```

Which I update and then use its value:

```
setOffersList([...offersList, newOfferProperties])

const updateProperties = {
  id: auctionId,
  key: 'offersLog',
  newValue: offersList
}
```

The issue is that inside `updateProperties`, the state value that assigned to the key `newValue` is not

the *latest* value (offer in this context), but the one before last because of the asynchronous nature of `useState()`

How can I solve this?

Comment: `const newList =[...offersList, newOfferProperties]; setOffersList(newList); const updateProperties ={ newValue: newList. ..}`?

Comment: generally, you get rid of the async problems by doing everything with the state as late as possible.

If you do not need to show the information to the user then you might as well keep it in standard variable for,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue comes while trying to update the state within a fired event.
What you need to do in this case is to assign the new value of the state in a variable first and then use this variable for state updating and updateProperties.

```
const newOfferList = [...offersList, newOfferProperties];

setOffersList(newOfferList);

const updateProperties = {
    id: auctionId,
    key: 'offersLog',
    newValue: newOfferList
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`setState` is asyn. You are accessing the `offersList` before it is being updated. You can pass the `newOfferProperties` to `offersList`.

```
const updateProperties = {
  id: auctionId,
  key: 'offersLog',
  newValue: [...offersList, newOfferProperties]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a flaw. You can't use setOffersList right after setState().
What you should do instead is to warp setOffersList in a function or in useEffect hook upon actions. Then your component will be re-render and your updateProperties gets the latest state

```
const [offersList, setOffersList] = useState(currentOffers)

function updateOfferList() {
  setOffersList([...offersList, newOfferProperties])
}

// or update the offerList in a useEffect hook on some conditions 

const updateProperties = {
  id: auctionId,
  key: 'offersLog',
  newValue: offersList
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass an [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to `setOffersList` to use the latest value. You can also [memoize](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) `updateProperties` so that it updates when the relevant dependencies change.

```js
setOffersList((prevList) => [...prevList, newOfferProperties]);

const updateProperties = React.useMemo(() => ({
  id: auctionId,
  key: 'offersLog',
  newValue: offersList
}), [auctionId, offersList]);
```